# RewriteEngine On and other 3 line

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know that using  these index.php file will not show in url.But I wondering what are the task of each line here.Can any one explain me each line.Who write these ugly code anyway ;)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Start by reading up on the directives used in the manual. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Ok I'm going to read.Dont go anywhere.I'm coming back shortly :-) @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteEngine On` - tell the webserver to rewrite

`RewriteCond` - are conditions (like IF), those two lines basically say:

"If the requested filename is NOT a physical file (`!-f`) in the filesystem"
and
"If the requested filename is NOT a physical directory (`!-d`) in the filesystem"

then do

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 1 - enables Mod Rewrite for this URL.

Line 2 - means "If REQUEST_FILENAME is not a file".

Line 2 - means "If REQUEST_FILENAME is not a directory".

Line 3 - "... then get all symbols after URL of the directory where this .htaccess is located in, and call index.php/*all-symbols-here*".